# Proving an inequality with induction

Tags: inequality, induction

> Show that for $n\geq 2$,
>   $$1^{-1/2}+2^{-1/2}+3^{-1/2}+\dots+n^{-1/2}>n^{1/2}.$$

I tried to prove this one by many ways, but couldn't make it.

Thanks.

Comment: have you solved the case $n=2$?

Comment: It's a very known problem. Search please this forum.

Comment: Yes, 1^(-1/2) + 2^(-1/2) > 2^(1/2)

Comment: From $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1/2}>n^{1/2}$ we get that $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k^{-1/2}>n^{1/2}+(n+1)^{-1/2}$. If you can prove that $n^{1/2}+(n+1)^{-1/2}>(n+1)^{1/2}$ you are done. Try writing the latter as $\frac{n^{1/2}((n+1)^{1/2}-n^{1/2})}{(n+1)^{1/2}}>0$, which is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the beginning is $n=2$ and we have $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}>\sqrt{2}$ this is true, since $\sqrt{2}>1$
and now we assume that for $n=k$ is hold that:
$$1^{-1/2}+2^{-1/2}+3^{-1/2}+...+k^{-1/2}>k^{1/2}$$
and now we have to Show that
$$1^{-1/2}+2^{-1/2}+3^{-1/2}+...+k^{-1/2}+(k+1)^{-1/2}>(k+1)^{1/2}$$
and now we have to Show that
$$k^{1/2}+(k+1)^{-1/2}>(k+1)^{1/2}$$
multiplying the last inequality by $(k+1)^{1/2}$ we get
$$k^{1/2}(k+1)^{1/2}+1>k+1$$
the last inequality is true since we have $k>0$